# How to boot Acer aspire 3 from external drive with lunix

Tags: boot, windows, bios

I just bought a new laptop, an Acer aspire 3, and I'm trying to run my external hard drive on it. It has Linux mint installed in it. But I can't find the boot option on the bios. I've disabled the secure boot, enabled the boot menu and tried all the usb ports. And it just doesn't appear. I've used this hard drive in 3 different computers now, one with Windows 10 and the other 2 on Windows 7. I don't know what I'm missing with this one. Also have to say that I'm not an expert on this subject. Anyone knows how to do it?

Edit:

I show the bios in the next pictures:

In the last one I also show the submenu of BOOT MODE, it only has the uefi option.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is USB boot enabled in the BIOS? Needless to say, if it's not, then you aren't going to see your USB HDD as a boot device.

Comment: @NasirRiley I've been looking for that option on the bios, but I can't find it. Is it like that?
USB BOOT: [DISABLED] ??

Comment: Yes. You also need to enable the F12 boot menu and change the boot mode to LEGACY. It's probably set to UEFI.

Comment: @NasirRiley I already enabled the f12 boot menu, and it doesnt have a legacy mode. See the edit of the question with the pictures of the bios.

Comment: Disable secure boot. If that doesn't work, then you'll need to format the USB as FAT32, use Rufus https://rufus.ie/ to put the ISO on it, and set the Target System as UEFI. You can do all of this from within Rufus itself by selecting the same options that you see in the photo on the website.